# How to use list of number in in clause-mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i am using where  in clause in my SQL Statement, which like this

```
select * from user_image where product_id in =product_id
```

product_id is the result value of another sql statement which is like this

```
select product_id from products ORDER BY views DESC
```

as we cannot use order by in the inner select statement i am trying it in this way.
but the problem here is the resultset of product_id is some thing like this [1,2,5,3,7,2] where as i need like this (1,2,5,3,7,2) so that in statement can be executed.

DataBase i am using is mysql

please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

join or subquery

join

```
select i.* from user_image as i inner join products as p on i.product_id = p.product_id;
```

subquery

```
select * from user_image where product_id in (select product_id from products)
```

Comment: i am using order by with desc value and in mysql we cant use order by in sub query it seems...

Comment: in sub query, order by is useless.both result IN ( 1,2,3) and IN ( 3,2,1) is same.